# Clobber another git branch with uncommitted contents of current branch subdirectory

Tags: git, hook, jekyll

I use *jekyll* to build my site in a **gh-pages** branch. I want to commit the generated contents from the `_site/` directory into the root of another (local) branch (called **web-site**, for example), replacing all of its contents.

I don't want to commit `_site/` to the the **gh-pages** branch, only the **web-site** branch.

My current process involves:

```
(gh-pages)$ jekyll build --config _config-production.yml
(gh-pages)$ mv _site/ ../
(gh-pages)$ git checkout web-site
(web-site)$ rm -rf * # remove all current contents except dotfiles
(web-site)$ mv ../_site/* . && rmdir ../_site/
(web-site)$ git commit -a
```

This seems terribly inefficient and error prone. Is there a way to clobber the contents of another branch with the uncommitted contents of a subdirectory, preferably in the form of a hook that runs the jekyll build and auto-commits to the second branch whenever I commit to the first branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963533/196405), I was able to create a fully-tested solution which does exactly what I needed:

```sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

build_jekyll_site() {
  # $1 is the expected source branch
  local source_br; source_br=$1
  # $2 is the name of the target branch
  local tgt_br; tgt_br=$2
  # $3 jekyll config file to build
  local config; config=$3

  local cur_branch; cur_branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD) || return 1

  # skip execution on other branches
  [[ $cur_branch == "refs/heads/$source_br" ]] || return 0

  # create message
  local message; message="Jekyll build from $source_br:$(git rev-parse --verify 'HEAD^{commit}' | cut -c1-7)"$'\n'$'\n'"$(git cat-file commit HEAD | sed '1,/^$/d')"

  # import git utils: needed for die, require_clean_work_tree
  . "$(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup" || return 1

  # ensure target branch exists
  local target_branch; target_branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "$tgt_br" 2>/dev/null) || die "fatal: $tgt_br is not a branch"
  case "$target_branch" in
    refs/heads/*)
      true
      ;;
    *)
      die "fatal: $tgt_br is not a branch"
      ;;
  esac

  # don't build what's not checked in
  require_clean_work_tree

  # check that jekyll config file exists
  [[ -f $config ]] || die "fatal: $config is not a file or does not exist"

  # build using jekyll 3
  local regex
  regex='^jekyll 3[.](0[.][3-9][0-9]*|0[.][1-2][0-9]+|[1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)'
  local jekyll
  jekyll=$(jekyll -v 2>/dev/null)
  [[ $jekyll =~ $regex ]] || die "fatal: requires jekyll >= 3.0.3 to build"

  # prep the working location
  local workdir; workdir=$(mktemp -d --tmpdir jekyll-XXXXXXXXXX) || die "fatal: unable to allocate a temporary directory"
  trap "rm -rf '""$workdir""'" 0 1 2 3 15

  # actually generate the site
  jekyll build --config "$config" --destination "$workdir/_site" --safe || die "fatal: jekyll build failure"

  # prepare and commit to the target branch
  export GIT_INDEX_FILE="$workdir/index"
  git --work-tree="$workdir/_site" add . || die "fatal: error adding $workdir/_site"
  local tree; tree=$(git write-tree) || die "fatal: error writing tree"
  local commit; commit=$(git commit-tree "$tree" -p "$target_branch" -m "$message") || die "fatal: error writing commit"
  git update-ref -m "$message" "$target_branch" "$commit" || die "fatal: error updating ref"

  return 0
}

build_jekyll_site 'gh-pages' 'web-site' '_config-production.yml'
```

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing of Jekyll, but to make a new commit on a particular branch without disturbing the current branch or staging area in any way, you will need to:

- set a temporary index file;
- populate that index file;
- use `git write-tree` to turn it into a top level tree;
- use `git commit-tree` to make a commit from that tree; and
- use `git update-ref` to update the desired branch name.

After the `commit-tree` step you can discard the temporary index.

Totally untested but should get you started:

```
#! /bin/sh

# commit-dir-to-branch: given a directory ($1) and branch
# name ($2), make a new commit on the target branch that
# consists of that directory's contents.

# NB: totally untested!

# Get git script goodies.
. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

# Make sure target directory exists.
dir="$1"
[ -d "$dir" ] || die "fatal: $dir is not a directory"

# Make sure branch name exists and names an actual branch
# (note: symbolic refs get resolved here, we could check
# and reject a symbolic ref too).
branch="$2"
fullbranch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "$2") || exit 1
case "$fullbranch" in
refs/heads/*) ;;
*) die "fatal: $branch does not name a branch"
esac

# Choose new temp index file, make sure to clean it up on
# exit, interrupt, etc.
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || die "fatal: unable to create temp index"
rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE
trap "rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE 0 1 2 3 15"
export GIT_INDEX_FILE

# Now fill in the index from the directory.
#
# Note that we don't override ignore files (.git/info/exclude,
# core.excludesFile, etc).  This may be a feature or a bug...
git --work-tree="$dir" add . || die "fatal: error adding $dir"

# Write the tree, and make a commit.  The new commit's parent
# is the commit currently at the head of the target branch.
#
# We probably should allow -m and -F arguments to this script
# for setting the message, rather than just supplying "autocommit"
# here.
tree=$(git write-tree) || die "fatal: error writing tree"
commit=$(git commit-tree -p $fullbranch -m "autocommit from $dir") ||
    die "fatal: error writing commit"

# Finally, update the branch ref.  Finishing the script will
# remove the temporary index.
git update-ref -m "autocommit from $dir" $fullbranch $commit
```

Comment: There is so much awesomeness in this, git commands I wasn't even aware of, etc... will definitely try this out and let you know if it works! Thanks!